# How to run manual builds with a different default parameter value than automatically scheduled builds?

Tags: teamcity

We have a TeamCity project that contains hundreds of build configurations.  The project schedules them to run nightly.  Often, developers will want to re-run some of these build configurations with custom parameters (their own development branch, for example).

I would like to have the value of a build parameter that exports our build results to `true` for all of my automatically scheduled builds.  I'd like this same parameter to default to `false` for all custom (manual) builds but still allow some users to set it to `true` if needed.  Is this possible?

The reason this "default" is so important is because most users running custom builds don't want to export the build results.  Requiring them to change the parameter from `true` (as it should be for automatic builds) to `false` (as it should be for 99% of custom builds) isn't viable.

I'm on TeamCity Enterprise 2019.2.1

I'm looking through my build configuration, but I can't see any distinction between parameters for scheduled runs and parameters for custom runs.

Answer (score 0):

In recent TeamCity versions it's possible to add custom parameters to builds triggered via schedule trigger (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-schedule-triggers.html#Triggered+Build+Customization):

[image]

If your version doesn't support that feature you could trigger your build (A) via another build (B):

1. Add schedule trigger to B
2. In B trigger A via REST API call with parameter customization (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/start-and-cancel-builds.html#Start+Custom+Build)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like either of these features are in 2019.2.1.  I think the custom trigger parameters would have been a great solution if my TC version was newer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that [reverse dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.2/predefined-build-parameters.html#PredefinedBuildParameters-OverridingDependenciesProperties) will work for my project configuration.

Our scheduled builds--the ones that require the `export` parameter to be set to `true`-- are kicked off by project that includes them as dependencies.  In the configuration for this project, I included a reverse dependency `reverse.dep.*.export`.

In the configurations for the builds themselves, the `export` parameter is defaulted to `false`.  Therefore, anytime a user runs a single build, the `export` parameter is `false` unless they modify the build parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).